# Can anyone explain this mule3 code please?

Tags: java, xml, mule, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

It is my first project from mule 3 to mule 4 conversion. I worked with mule4 but new in mule3.
Can anyone please help me.....?
Could you please tell me the use of these custom processor and transformer in this mule3 code? and what will be the equivalent code in mule4?
There is no custom transformer in mule 4 like this.
Please help me..

```
 <configuration defaultProcessingStrategy="non-blocking" doc:name="Configuration"/>
   <context:property-placeholder location="config.properties"/>
    <expression-language:property-placeholder location="config.properties" />
    {Configuration for Listener}
   {Configuration for Request}

    <spring:bean name="copyInboundToOutboundPropertiesTransformer"
            class="org.mule.transformer.TransformerTemplate">
            <spring:constructor-arg>
            <spring:bean class="org.mule.transport.http.construct.support.CopyInboundToOutboundPropertiesTransformerCallback"/>
            </spring:constructor-arg>
   </spring:bean>
    
    <flow name="proxy" >
        {Listener Component}
        <custom-processor class="com.mulesoft.gateway.extension.ProxyRequestHeadersProcessor" doc:name="Custom Processor"/>
        <transformer ref="copyInboundToOutboundPropertiesTransformer" />
       {Request Component}
        <custom-processor class="com.mulesoft.gateway.extension.ProxyResponseHeadersProcessor" doc:name="Custom Processor"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do some HTTP header processing. See https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/2.x/proxy-mule3-elements

This looks like an auto generated proxy created by [API Manager](https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/2.x/api-proxy-landing-page). You should not attempt to migrate those custom components. Try to generate a new auto generated proxy for Mule 4. If you don't have access to API Manager just ignore them. Probably Mule 4 has the functionality built in.